# IBOutlet and IBAction Connections From Class to Main Window NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to link IBOutlets and IBActions from a class file to the main program window? I know how to do this in the main program (@property in the .h file and @synthesize in the .m file) and then make the connections in the AppDelegate section of the XIB file. Can this be done in a separate class file? I have tried adding the @property and @synthesize commands to the class .h and .m files but I can’t make the link in AppDelegate.

Thank you.
Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, go to the `MainMenu.xib`, and look at the bottom right for the `Object Library`.  Search for "View Controller" and drag that into your `Document Outline` which is the object hierarchy viewer on the left of the canvas. Now set the class of this "View Controller" in the `Identity Inspector` to be your custom class.  Make sure your custom `NSViewController` has the `IBOutlets` you want.

Now you can ctrl click and drag your views to the "View Controller" in the `Document Outline`, and a little popup will show up asking you which `IBOutlet` you would like to connect it to

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I followed what you said up to dragging the "View Controller" into the Document Outline. I then "Showed" the Identity Inspector and got lost. FYI - the name of my class is LoadButtons. What do I enter in the Class and Module fields? Do I enter anything into the Restoration ID field? Am I placing the IBOutlets and IBActions in my LoadButtons .h file? Thanks!

Comment: The `Identity Inspector` has a field called `Class` which is at the top.  Put `LoadButtons` there.  Leave Module and Restoration ID alone.  If you place them in the Header file (.h) they will be public to other Classes.  If you put it in your Implementation file (.m) they will be private to your `LoadButtons` class & the xib that has a reference to it.  For your case I would say put it in your .m file

Comment: Hi. Apparently I am doing something wrong. In the field where you say to enter LoadButtons, the text NSViewController is already in the Class field and it is grey text and it won't accept changes. I type in LoadButtons but it doesn't stick, it reverts back to NSViewController. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if I have described my problem very well. I don't want multiple windows or views in my app. I only want one main window but I want to be able to access NS objects in it it from a class file I have created. Is the View Controller the right way to go? Keith

Comment: The gray text means that it's a default cocoa class.  Just type LoadButtons (if that indeed is the name of your custom class that inherits from NSViewController), and hit enter/return to save the changes.  

You described your problem fine, and this approach is fine.  You just need to have the IBOutlets in your custom class `LoadButtons`, and then include a reference to your custom class in your `MainMenu.xib` by dragging in the `View Controller` object into your xib.

Comment: Got it working, thank you for being so patient with me. This was a real learning experience and I know more now than when I posted this question. Keith

Comment: Not a problem, nice job :)